# can apache "fetch and return" 302/301 redirects when proxying?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

So im using ProxyPass directives to redirect to an internally hosted API:

```
ProxyPass /api/ http://internal.api.server/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://internal.api.server/
```

Which all works fine.
Unfortunately, the client has a bug in which it can't handle 301/302 redirects properly. The API returns redirections for certain actions, in proper RESTful style, indicating for instance where to go to see the new thing you have just created with a POST.

Anyway, is there any way to configure apache to fetch the content from 302 target location & return it for the original request?

ie, at the moment:

- browser asks for /api/will-redirect.json
- apache proxys that to the internal api
- api respond with 302:/api/final-location.json
- apache reverse proxies that to the client
- client dies because it cant deal with 302

What i would like:

- browser asks for /api/will-redirect.json
- apache proxys that to the internal api
- api respond with 302:/api/final-location.json
- apache fetches /api/final-location.json
- apache returns the content of /api/final-location.json to the client ( as 200 )

Effectively making the 302's invisible to the client. Possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144286/how-to-tell-apache-in-reverse-proxy-mode-to-intercept-or-trap-302-responses-fro - In short, not without writing your own software to do it